# How to reset Keyboard Shortcuts on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10

I can't set back <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd> and "reset all" doesn't work too!

What happened with Ubuntu....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 17.10 can't change the input switching shortcut to alt+shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this shortcut from GNOME Tweaks (`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`). It is reintroduction of well known [bug 1218322](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322) .

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/967493/66509) for screenshots.