# Ubuntu 17.10. Keyboard layout switching became much slower

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

After migration from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10 I experience a problem with the keyboard switching. When I press `shift+alt` it takes about 500ms for the switching between the layouts. With Ubuntu 16.04 it didn't take so much time.

After upgrade I updated my `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
  1 # KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE                                                                                                                                                                            
  2 
  3 # Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
  4 
  5 XKBMODEL="pc105"
  6 XKBLAYOUT="pl,de,ru"
  7 XKBVARIANT=""
  8 XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"
  9 
  10 BACKSPACE="guess"
```

And `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options['grp:alt_shift_toggle']` says:

```
['grp:alt_shift_toggle']
```

Comment: You may use default combinations (super+space, shift+super+space). They should work faster.

Comment: yeah, but they really suck. There is some strange overlay with all possible layouts, I don't need it. I just want my old convenience.

Comment: I understand. For some reason they're not encouraging that combo. Apparently it cannot be even set easily: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift

Comment: Also the overlay appears if you press and hold a bit longer. A quick press and release should change the layout without showing the overlay.