# How to NOT show keyboard layout chooser popup when changing language in GNOME 3

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, language-support

Since I installed 17.10, when switching language with the assigned keyboard shortcut I get this switcher "window" that obstructs me from typing for a couple of seconds. And yes, a couple of seconds is a huge amount of time when switching languages a lot.

[image: huge focus-grabbing language-switching indicator]

This happens both in X11 and Wayland but doesn't happen (the obstructive window will not appear) when I switch language by clicking on the lang indicator on top bar. Is there any way to tell this window "please go away"?

Answer (score 5):

I've built the [Quick Lang Switch](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4559/quick-lang-switch/) Gnome-shell extension exactly to avoid the switcher popup - now switching languages happens instantly.
Plus, it does not require a *custom-shortcut* (the regular one changes behavior), so login-screen is not affected.

***Disclaimer**: I am the developer of the Quick Lang Switch...*

Comment: If it's a bug, please file an issue in [the extension's repo](https://github.com/ankostis/gnome-shell-quick-lang-switch).

Comment: Sorry, you're right; and the problem fixed itself somehow. Thanks for the plugin! (Deleting my previous comment)

Answer (score 4):

The overlay appears if you press and hold a bit longer. A quick press and release should change the layout without showing the overlay.

As a workaround you may set another keyboard shortcut to switch layouts, see this for reference: [Ubuntu 17.10 can't change the input switching shortcut to alt+shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift).

Comment: Yes, I could do what I wanted to, by assigning a new shortcut as you proposed. With my previous selection (that was pressing F2/F3) this window (the overlay, as you call it) would appear even if I pressed keys for a brief moment. Thank you.

Comment: I had always re-assigned lang switching to the F2/F3 keys instead of alt+shift, obviously because I prefer "one key" stroking instead of a combination. When I upgraded to 17.10 the F2/F3 switching was giving me this overlay. When I assigned a new key (ScrLk) the overlay will not appear, so I am more or less ok (although ScrLk is well away on the right and not comfortable for speed typing).

Comment: I'm pressing the key as fast as humanly possible, and the window still shows up (which is OK), and it steals keyboard focus (which is *not* OK).

Comment: @Flimm What 'bout the alternative shortcut (e.g. alt+shift) suggestion?

Comment: Setting another shortcut is forcing users to change common keys , break habits and also break compatibility with other systems.

I rather go back to windows.

I would not consider anything that comes close to 'design decision - take it or go away' to be a valid solution...

Comment: @user1656671 I know it's very upsetting right? I've got the same issue once switched to the wayland. Switch back to X11 with unity works as expected

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by querying gnome-shell via its JS interface with `gdbus call` ([src](https://www.mail-archive.com/gnome-shell-list@gnome.org/msg08988.html)).

The following script will alternate between two configured input sources.  Easy to modify if you have more.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cur_idx=$(
        gdbus call \
                --session \
                --dest org.gnome.Shell \
                --object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
                --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
                "imports
                        .ui.status
                        .keyboard
                        .getInputSourceManager()
                        .currentSource
                        .index" |
        cut -d"'" -f2
)

next_idx=$(( 1 - $cur_idx ))

gdbus call \
        --session \
        --dest org.gnome.Shell \
        --object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
        --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
        "imports
                .ui
                .status
                .keyboard
                .getInputSourceManager()
                .inputSources[$next_idx]
                .activate()" \
        &> /dev/null
```

Make it executable with `chmod a+x </path/to/script>` and you may then bind it to a  custom shortcut key:

Open *Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard* and click the '**+**' choice-button at the bottom to assign the script to some shortcut

(For Gnome < 3.x: *Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard -> Custom Shortcuts*).

Comment: Thank you, the script works flawlessly in SID+ latest Gnome-3.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to [security concerns](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3943),
*dbus* can no longer call method  `org.gnome.Shell.Eval` with arbitrary code,
since Gnome-shell v41 (e.g. pushed downstream to *Debian unstable "SID"* roughly on Sept 2021).  You need an extension [like this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4559/quick-lang-switch/) which additionally is much more responsive.

Comment: @ankostis, hey, take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1500831/171572). I've made an extension that works without the `Eval`, while sharing a similar D-Bus based approach.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very delayed answer and it might not be useful. But I wanted to share this with you guys.
I'm using Kubuntu 22.04 and I chose Wayland. I get the same thing here but I disabled it by right clicking the language icon in the taskbar.
Configure > Configure Layout.
Uncheck the option that says: OSD on layout change. And you are good to go.
No need to alter the shortcut, or do any scripting.[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't that KDE option only?  The Q here is explicitly for Gnome.