# What is the name of this window and how can I change it?

Tags: gnome, input-language

I want to slightly change the window that appears when switching the language (same as in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972926/how-to-not-show-this-window-when-changing-language)). Can someone suggest how this window is called and how can it be changed?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: It's not a window, it's GNOME's  on-screen display for input method switching, which was introduced in GNOME 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

The Input Source chooser shows the input sources you have enabled in *Region & Language*. Just add and/or remove sources to your liking.

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html