# Manipulate the Default Shortcut Super+Space for Switching to Next Input Source without Graphical Representation

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I have two commands those are binded with <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as mentioned in this Q&A [Modeless/stateless layout language switching with Caps Lock, again (18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1123163/739431)

My requirement is to toggle the languages with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> without graphical representation on screen.

[image]

I have disabled the default shortcuts for switch to next input source and previous input source.

[image]

now I can bind any command to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> like below

[image]

**Thoughts:**

It is possible to give these two commands as two shortcuts for example:

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for English
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for Ukranian

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[1].activate()"
```

When the value is 1 in "inputSource[ ]" the language changes to Ukranian and if it is 0 language changes to English

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
```

**Question:**

I am looking for a command that can read the present value and change to other value among 0 and 1 in the below command so that I can toggle the languages without the need of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
```

Comment: See [this git](https://github.com/Nekotekina/kbhook/blob/master/layout_rotate.sh).

Comment: @danzel can you post the script as answer.. credit goes to you..

Comment: that's not my script. I googled "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager" looking for some documentation, and the git repo was the first result. I actually don't use gnome so I cannot test it. Feel free to post it yourself if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @danzel, the link provided by him..https://github.com/Nekotekina/kbhook/blob/master/layout_rotate.sh

I have saved the below script as `~/SL.sh` and created a shortcut with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> as
`/bin/bash /home/pratap/SL.sh`

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT=`gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().currentSource.index"`

if [ "$CURRENT" == "(true, '1')" ]; then
  gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
else
  gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[1].activate()"
fi
```

now <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is toggling the Languages without graphical representation which I was looking for..

[image]

thanks to @danzel once again

Comment: Unfortunately calling dbus `org.gnome.Shell.Eval` method no longer works, ie since Gnome-shell v41, for [security reasons](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3943).

Answer (score 1):

The [Quick Lang Switch](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4559/quick-lang-switch/) Gnome-shell extension does exactly that, and switching languages happens instantaneously.
Plus, it fixes any focus stealing issues with current window while it does not require a *custom-shortcut* (the regular one changes behavior), so `gnome-tweak-tool` choices still work.

***Disclaimer**: I am the developer of the Quick Lang Switch...*

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to assign a unique shortcut for every input method you have (e.g. <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> for US, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> for UK, etc), I would recommend another GNOME Shell Extension: [Shyriiwook](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6691/shyriiwook/). It supports old (pre 45) and newer GNOMEs (45+). It's super simple and minimalist, it doesn't even have a GUI. After installing it, a new D-Bus interface will be exposed in your GNOME Shell Session, and you'll be able to manage input methods programmatically.

**Examples with CLI (`gdbus`).**

**Query current configuration with:**

```shell
$ gdbus introspect \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --only-properties

node /me/madhead/Shyriiwook {
  interface me.madhead.Shyriiwook {
    properties:
      readonly as availableLayouts = ['us', 'uk'];
      readonly s currentLayout = 'us';
  };
};
```

**Select input method by their ID with:**

```shell
$ gdbus call \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --method me.madhead.Shyriiwook.activate "uk"
```

This allows to use it in scripts and custom shortcuts very easily.

**Disclaimer**: I am the developer of this extension.

Comment: Hi @madhead sounds intresting, I did not test it yet. Will test soon.