# Switch layouts with one key on 18.04 (bug?)

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I want to switch layouts with <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, which conveniently sits under the right thumb on my ThinkPad keyboard. I configure it so in the Keyboard settings and it works! HOWEVER every time I press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, a giant layout indicator appears in the center of the screen and stays there for a couple of seconds. If the layouts are switched with <kbd>Shift+PrtSc</kbd>, then the indicator disappears quickly.

Is there any way to switch layouts without making the indicator appear at all? I'm asking because it used to work well on 15.10.

EDIT: Works, posted an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084210/500433) to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/972926/500433).

Answer (score 1):

As possible duplicate answers state - this is almost impossible in the GNOME Shell.

But it is possible in Unity. It is still available for 18.04 LTS.

You can install it with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop`.

Then setup your keyboard layout keys:

> - Switch to next source using <kbd>Print</kbd>
> - Switch to previous source using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>
>
> [image: PrintScreen and Shift+PrintScreen on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Unity]

It works as expected:

[image: Screencast with PrintScreen as layout switcher]

Comment: Possible via a hack, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1084210/500433.