# How to set right alt as switch to next input source on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

How to set <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> as a shortcut to switch to next input source on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is option to switch it from terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['Alt_R']"
```

Comment: May be there is also way to switch keyboard without pop-up window (I press enter to select the language and the selection window is gone, otherwise you have to wait 3 seconds)?

Comment: @DariaRomanova I agree, that language switch popup is annoying. I avoid it by using Gnome Extension quick-lang-switch@ankostis.gmail.com, link is https://github.com/ankostis/gnome-shell-quick-lang-switch

It was highlighted in Q&A as well https://askubuntu.com/questions/972926/how-to-not-show-keyboard-layout-chooser-popup-when-changing-language-in-gnome-3/1373109#1373109

Comment: You are a wizard!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via *Tweaks -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Switching to another layout*.

Note 1: The `gnome-tweaks` package needs to be installed.

Note 2: <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> for that purpose is not advisable if any of the layouts you use includes 3rd and 4th level symbols.