# Static ordering of keyboard layout switching in Ubuntu 17.10 and later with GNOME 3

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, input-language, xkb

Just installed Ubuntu 17.10 and it seems that the keyboard layout switching has changed its behavior.

In the previous version of Ubuntu (such as 16.04 Unity), if I have 3 different keyboard layouts (for example **EN**-**TH**-**JA**), hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> would *always* cycle to the next layout in the same order (e.g. **EN** to **TH** to **JA** then back to **EN**).

However since Ubuntu 17.10, this is no longer the case. It cycles through the layout in the ***MRU*** *(Most Recently Used)* ordering. So suppose that the layout starts with **EN**, then I cycled to **TH**. Next time I hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, it would give me **EN** instead of **JA**.

I tried to dig up and found that the culprit is the newly implemented DCONF settings inside `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` and there seems to be no way to change this behavior.

So my question is: Is there a way to change this behavior to **"static ordering"** of keyboard layout switching?

---

(As a side-note, the new behavior is very bad when we have three or more layouts. Most of the time we as a user couldn't remember the ***MRU*** layouts, so layout switching is very inconvenient and **much slower** than already knowing what the next layout would be if static ordering is used.)

If there is no settings to change this behavior, where should I report this as a bug or a feature request?

Comment: Alternative custom [shortcuts like shift + alt](https://askubuntu.com/q/967364/) will probably work as you want. Also is this a big problem? Doesn't super + space give a visual cue by showing an [overlay containing available layouts](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/figures/input-methods-switcher.png) while switching? (You'll have to press and hold slightly longer though! A quick press and release won't work.)

Comment: @pomsky I would be pretty unhappy with having to rely on a visual cue.  It’s far better in my opinion to just be able to use a keybinding without having to bother with checking for any visual feedback.

Comment: Unity still does it the old way. A feature request should be filed [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=gnome-control-center).

Comment: @pomsky **[Shift]+[Alt]** indeed worked as intended! However, this seems to be arbitrary and a bit inconsistent (considering that I still cannot disable **[Super]+[Space]**).

As @.Guildenstern has mentioned, relying on visual cue significantly slows down the typing speed. I guess many people with 3+ layouts would actually prefer to at least have options to consistently use static cycling.

I'm going to file a feature request as @.GunnarHjalmarsson suggested.

Comment: The feature request has been filed here. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790273
Thanks everyone.

Comment: @AbhabongseJanthong commented the issue, we actually need this!

Comment: I would not generalize this as _"very bad"_ for everyone, in fact many users (like me) have to switch between [some input source] to their native language input source. When an app is made for QWERTY keyboard, I have to switch between EN and FR for the other applications ; when speaking Japanese I have to switch between JA and FR ; same when I use an external keyboard (switch between BE and FR). So most of the time I switch between 2 sources and MRU is good

Comment: @N.Cornet what's different with having **EN-FR-JA** ? there's a previous shortcut also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround you may set an alternative keyboard shortcut like <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> to switch between keyboard layouts (see this question for reference: [Ubuntu 17.10 can't change the input switching shortcut to alt+shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift)).

This shortcut should obey the "static ordering" you're looking for.

---

<sub>A feature request has been filed by OP [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790273).</sub>

Comment: This is definitely a good workaround for the time being. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GNOME 3's D-Bus API offers the `org.gnome.Shell.Eval` method for executing arbitrary JavaScript, and thus we can monkey-patch the code into not changing the order.

Here's a script that works on GNOME 40 (Ubuntu 21.10):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash

read -r -d '' patch_script << '{ENDOFMSG}'
Object.getPrototypeOf(imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager())._currentInputSourceChanged = function () {
  let oldSource;
  [oldSource, this._currentSource] = [this._currentSource, newSource];

  this.emit('current-source-changed', oldSource);

  // for (let i = 1; i < this._mruSources.length; ++i) {
  //   if (this._mruSources[i] == newSource) {
  //     let currentSource = this._mruSources.splice(i, 1);
  //     this._mruSources = currentSource.concat(this._mruSources);
  //     break;
  //   }
  // }
  this._changePerWindowSource();
}
{ENDOFMSG}

gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "$patch_script"
```