# How to prevent gnome to change the language input order when switching languages?

Tags: gnome, keyboard

Here's my input settings (notice the order of the languages in the list which is my preference.)

[image]

Now initially when I invoke the shortcut to switch the input the list looks like that (as expected) :

[image]

Now I select Korean input (second item) and invoke the switch shortcut again, here's how the list looks like :

[image]

As you can see the order changed.
And now if I select another input and try to switch again the list is completely shifted.

**Is there a way to prevent gnome from rearranging the list all the time ?**

I think it's worth mentioning my job is about languages and I switch languages all the time (searching a chinese character, going back to english keyboard, going back to a korean dictionary to find out a definition, etc ...), I found that the brain remembers more easily the location of the languages in the list rather than what's actually written, and that's how Windows do.
I wish there's a way to fix that, if not I would have to report that as an issue on the gnome website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: gnome is enough detail but can you also mention your 0S??

Comment: @PRATAP my OS is fedora. Thanks for providing this link which is helpful, this is exactly what my question refers to. Unfortunately it seems that gnome still haven't provided a solution to this problem regarding the bug report is 2 years old. After all one solution would be to make a script that waits for the shortcuts and then call a tool like `localectl` to change the input. But I wish that was a built-in option. again thanks for your help.

Comment: @PRATAP i will try using `xbindkeys` thanks for suggestion

Comment: so, your requirement is Visual + Static Changing rite..?? where Super+space doing visual but not other and Shift+Alt is doing Static and not other.. Correct?

Comment: @PRATAP Correct. ah yes right, the problem with the solution proposed in the link (`Alt+Shift`) is that it lacks a visual feedback, and can't use shortcut for previous (like `win+shift+space` to go back one input). So it's not really satisfying. Again I switch often the languages and it's more easy to memorize the location of the current input (highlighted) and move from 1, 2, 3, 4, ... positions. Do you understand ?

Comment: @PRATAP thanks! If I have time I will try to make a polyfill script, the only problem is I don't know well how I could make a visual feedback (centered in the screen) like the gnome interface.

Comment: Hi.. I am reading your comment about 1 2 3 4 positions..  Do you want 1 2 3 4 to stick like that? I think If you avoid MRU the order would be smthng like 2 3 4 1 or 3 4 1 2 or 1 2 3 4 or 4 1 2 3. are you looking for 1 2 3 4 always to show on screen and the highlighter will start from any location as 0pp0sed to present behaviour which is 2nd or 4th (Su+Sp n Shift+Su+Space)??

Comment: @PRATAP yes 1234 sticky position, hence your answer was exactly what I needed ;) thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, there is no gnome-shell-extension as of now for the static shifting of keyboard layout using default shortcuts Super+Space and Shift+Super+Space..

and the comments about this link [Static ordering of keyboard layout switching in Ubuntu 17.10 and later with GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/q/975749/739431) from OP

> the problem with the solution proposed in the link (Alt+Shift) is that
>   it lacks a visual feedback, and can't use shortcut for previous (like
>   win+shift+space to go back one input). So it's not really satisfying.

I could achieve at least one point out of two (Visual Feedback & Switching back to previous layout) with below workaround.

***Workaround***

OS: Ubuntu 19.10

Reference: [Manipulate the Default Shortcut Super+Space for Switching to Next Input Source without Graphical Representation](https://askubuntu.com/q/1134629/739431)

Create two scripts with below contents, I have named those as "SuSpace.sh" and "ShSuSpace.sh"

SuSpace.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

totalLang=$(gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager()._mruSources.length" | grep -oP "(?<=').*?(?=')")

currentLang=$(gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().currentSource.index" | grep -oP "(?<=').*?(?=')")

declare -i math=$currentLang+1

if [ "$math" -lt "$totalLang" ]; then
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources["$currentLang+1"].activate()"
else
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
fi
```

ShSuSpace.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

totalLang=$(gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager()._mruSources.length" | grep -oP "(?<=').*?(?=')")

currentLang=$(gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().currentSource.index" | grep -oP "(?<=').*?(?=')")

declare -i math=$currentLang-1

if [ "$math" -eq -1 ]; then
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources["$totalLang-1"].activate()"
else
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources["$currentLang-1"].activate()"
fi
```

you can create custom shortcuts for these two scripts as per your wish.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a tone!!!! I placed these 2 scripts in `/usr/local/bin` and used gnome shortcuts interface and now it works perfectly! That's like a Christmas gift in my busy days:) I will definitely try to find a tool for visual feedback but now that I have the backbone I should have the motivation. I don't know how to thank you, again thanks..