# What is the difference between mru-sources and sources in dconf /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources?

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-gnome

```
dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/sources
```

has the same output as

```
dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/mru-sources
```

which is

```
[('xkb', 'ch+de_nodeadkeys'), ('xkb', 'us')]
```

**What is the difference**?
Should I always modify both? If not, when/why not?

Comment: I see, thanks @PRATAP. Does that mean that `mru-sources` will be irrelevant when one modifies `sources` to add an additional keyboard layout? Could you perhaps come up with an example when one would want to modify MRU?

Comment: Thank you. You've clarified what I was wondering about. You're welcome to write that as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dconf lines..

Input Sources are your priority.. say you have 4 languages 1 2 3 4... if you add 5th language its position will be at 5th. That means your input sources will be 1 2 3 4 5. In future if you delete 3rd language.. your input sources will become 1 2 3 4 where 4 & 5 takes 3 & 4 positions.

MRU is Most Recently Used.. it varies based on your usage.. means input sources are always in that order 1 2 3 4 and MRU varies based on which language you chose most recently..

you may go through post for further understanding..
[How to prevent gnome to change the language input order when switching languages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197856/how-to-prevent-gnome-to-change-the-language-input-order-when-switching-languages)