# How to hide the prompt-like thing when changing input source?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, ibus, ibus-avro

I am using ibus-avro on Ubuntu 20.04. I have 2 input sources: en, bn. I am using <kbd>F8</kbd> to switch the sources. When switching, a large prompt-like thing (I don't know the exact term) is shown on screen. I cannot take a screenshot of it (<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> is not working while it is visible), but it looks something like this:

[image: prompt-like thing looks like this]

It is annoying, and it also seems to prevent typing for a moment until it goes away. How to hide this and just switch the input source instantly? Thanks.

UPDATE: This issue does not seem that annoying when using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for switching input sources. In those cases, it only seems to be visible as long as the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> (respectively) key is held down.

Comment: One way is to create commands and attach them to F8. Otherway is to patch the gnome-shell code.

Comment: SuSpace.sh script in this link is one possibility to bind the script to F8 Key. https://askubuntu.com/a/1198150/739431

Comment: You can also use gnome tweaks to change the input sources without notification on screen but that don't accept single key from Fn keys

Comment: @UnKNOWn I just tried Ctrl+Space and also Super+Space from the keyboard shortcuts settings and none of them seems to have this issue. However, I would prefer using F8. Need to try the script I guess.

Comment: Yes but is F8 Choosable as a Keybinding??

Comment: @UnKNOWn From here, yes: Settings --> Keyboard Shortcuts --> Typing --> Switch to next input source. That also auto-changes the Switch to previous input source shortcut to Shift+F8.

Comment: If you can assign shortcut key to F8.. you can bind F8 to run the above script. Have you tried that?

Comment: @UnKNOWn Yes, it's working! I modified the script a little bit though (mainly replaced the `math` variable with `$((currentLang+1))`), then saved it as an executable, added it as a shortcut from the Keyboard Shortcuts settings, and it works. Thanks. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Workaround Only***

You can create an executable script with below content and bind the script to <kbd>F8</kbd> Key

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

totalLang=$(gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager()._mruSources.length" | grep -oP "(?<=').*?(?=')")

currentLang=$(gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().currentSource.index" | grep -oP "(?<=').*?(?=')")

math=$((currentLang+1))

if [ "$math" -lt "$totalLang" ]; then
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources["$currentLang+1"].activate()"
else
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
fi
```