# How do I change input language without having to confirm it?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, language-support

Everytime I change an input language using grave accent key it doesnt change instantly. There will be a popup of languages to choose between and I have to hit enter to apply the change. How do I change input language in 1 click without having to confirm it? The screenshot of the problem is attached here

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1347062/739431

Comment: gnome-tweaks can also do. Install gnome-tweaks

Comment: which function on gnome tweaks? installed but cant find the right function to fix it

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/739431

Comment: cool thanks. found the code that fixed my problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134629/manipulate-the-default-shortcut-superspace-for-switching-to-next-input-source-w?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manipulate the Default Shortcut Super+Space for Switching to Next Input Source without Graphical Representation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134629/manipulate-the-default-shortcut-superspace-for-switching-to-next-input-source-w)

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT=`gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().currentSource.index"`

if [ "$CURRENT" == "(true, '1')" ]; then
  gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
else
  gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[1].activate()"
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am happy that you found a solution to your question and posted the answer so that it will help others. Please explain what this code does, and how and where to save it, how to use it.