# How to disable change language notification in ubuntu 18.04 GNOME?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, gnome-shell, input-language

Whenever I change language layout, this notification appears and after 3 seconds disappear and I do not want to see this notification.

[image: layout switcher pop-up]

Comment: Are you sure you see that thing in Unity? If not, please edit your question to reflect the desktop environment you are using.

Comment: yes i am sure my desktop is unity

Comment: @LinuxAsaad What's the output of the following command in Terminal: `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`?

Comment: sorry, i thought my desktop was unity i did not care that is gnome. after run the above command, output was gnome

Comment: it overlay - crazy thing. It blocks any shortcuts with Ctrl+Shift. For example it is not possible to press Ctrl+Shift+P in Sublime for control panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That language indicating overlay is part of the GNOME shell, so probably not so easy to switch it off completely.

As a workaround you may set another alternative keyboard shortcut to switch between input languages, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> which will not show the overlay. To do so, follow the Q&A: [Ubuntu 17.10 can't change the input switching shortcut to alt+shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift).

Answer (score 3):

1. Turn OFF default values: **Settings => Keyboard Shortcuts => Typing**
   [image]
2. Install **gnome-tweaks** and turn on your new key layouts:
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

My solution for 18.04 LTS. As a Thai people, we have a norm to use the <kbd>`</kbd> key to switch between en/th. So I try it too, and found out that when I chose (pressed) <kbd>`</kbd> key in the settings 'Switch to the next input source', the system automatically choose <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> in 'Switch to the previous input source' for me. And with this settings, when I pressed only <kbd>`</kbd> ..I got a pop-up too. But when I try hold-pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and then pressed <kbd>`</kbd> ..NOW it's has no pop-up!. This more safety than the default '<kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>(press these in simultaneously)' that can sometime-freezed the desktop. (But if you have to or want to use `` ` `` or `~` (both are on the same key) you can still copy it from characters map.)

Answer (score 1):

There is special gnome shell extension [gnome-shell-quick-lang-switch](https://github.com/ankostis/gnome-shell-quick-lang-switch) to hide language popup.