# How to prevent focus from window on top when switching language

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, language-support

I'm surprised that I didn't find a solution for that online. Or in configs, actually.

The setup is that I have a different language on every window, and I have a window (terminal) set to be on top. Now, I want to switch a language in one of the windows that is not on top. If I'm doing this with the mouse, then there is no problem. Using a keyboard shortcut, on the other hand, results with the language being changed on the window that is set on top. I can undo that by setting the window that is on top to not still focus, but I don't always want that.

So is there a way to solve this?

Comment: From your question I do not think this is what you meant to say. with the mouth As for your issue no I do not think you can have a short cut key affect other then the current window, maybe with some kind of script.

Answer (score 0):

I think the animation is what messes it up, if you disable it as per:

[How to disable change language notification in ubuntu 18.04 GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033338/how-to-disable-change-language-notification-in-ubuntu-18-04-gnome)

keyboard-shortcut changes the language on the active window correctly.

Comment: You should flag for duplicate (when you have 15 rep), instead of answering with a link to another question.