# Ubuntu 18.04 Can't assign shift to keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.04

I've Ubuntu 18.04 LTS freshly installed on my machine and I can't assign <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>arrows</kbd> to change workspaces just like **unity**.

Comment: this just works automatically for me... but with the new switcher it's only up and down. does that work?

Comment: and the change workspaces is just ctrl+alt+arrows (up down only, created automatically) with the shift is to move windows

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte Yes that's work. The problem as I described I can't assign the shift button to any shortcut

Answer (score 3):

I had that working fine in Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome, I just switched to 18.04 and noticed that.

It seems that input switching "Alt+Shift" conflicts with creating shortcuts desired for moving windows to new workspace.

1. Disable "Alt-Shift"

   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool

Open Tweaks -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Switch to another layout -> (uncheck Alt+Shift and choose a different combo if you need)

Reference: [Switching to another layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift/967493)

2. Change combinations to Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Arrow
   In keyboard settings -> Under "Navigation" -> Move window one workspace up/down -> Set shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+up/down)

Note:
Perhaps people with single input language won't notice this if the system is not configured for multiple input methods.