# Ubuntu 20.04 Custom Keyboard does not accept "Shift + Key" as new shortcut

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to assign `Shift + r` as a new keyboard shortcut to mouse right-click. Thus I walk through the process:

**Settings** -> **Keyboard Shortcuts** -> **Add Custom Shortcut**-> **Shortcut**

Then, when I press `Shift`, it does not recognize this key.

Why this is not allowed?

EDIT:
The solution from [Ubuntu 18.04 Can't assign shift to keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034168/ubuntu-18-04-cant-assign-shift-to-keyboard) does not fix the problem as the `Alt + Shift` box is already unchecked in my machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 Can't assign shift to keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034168/ubuntu-18-04-cant-assign-shift-to-keyboard)

Comment: duplicate question see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034168/ubuntu-18-04-cant-assign-shift-to-keyboard

Comment: Appreciated, but it doesn't solve the problem. In his solution, in "switching to another layout", the box "Alt + Shift" is already unchecked in my computer.

Comment: I think the point is you just cant use the shift key it is reserved by the system.

Comment: May I ask how you would write an uppercase `R` then?

Comment: @David I guess you are right...

Comment: @danzel edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observed, a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> combination is not allowed. Why? I think it protects casual users from assigning unexpected keyboard combinations. <kbd>Shift</kbd> keyboard combinations are too commonly used and are an essential part of daily typing. How will you type "D"?

That said, you can still make it to work if you insist. Assign, for the time being, a hotkey that is supported, e.g. `<Control><Shift>d`. Then, delve into dconf-editor (not installed by default). Under /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/, find the folder ("custom") that corresponds with your shortcut key, and edit the value to read `<Shift>d`.

Comment: Wow! That really worked for me, thanks!!

Comment: @gabriel-pimentel Welcome to Askubuntu! The way we say thanks here is by upvoting and accepting answers that work. This allows others with the same issue to find reliable answers. I highly recommend that you take the [tour.](https://askubuntu.com/tour)

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks!!