# Problem changing kayboard language

Tags: keyboard, input-language

I have Ubuntu 18.04. I cannot change my keyboard language. When I try with shortcut, nothing going on. When I try with clicking on the language and change it, the icon of the language changes, but when I writing the language is still English. I have only 2 languages - Bulgarian and English. I cannot switch to Bulgarian. Before 2-3 weeks everything worked fine, but now when turn on my laptop it doesn't work. I don't know what caused this.
If you have some questions do not hesitate to ask.

Edit: Actually I notice that even shortcuts for opening terminal does not work, so maybe there is some global problem with the shortcuts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your desktop environment? What is keyboard layout switching shortcut? Where did you set it? How many keyboard layouts do you have?

Comment: Hi, N0rbert,
My laptop configuration is: https://most.bg/e9y44ea-450-i7-4702mq-15-6-8gb.html 
My shortcut switching keyboard shortcut is: ALT + SHIFT
I have 2 layouts - BUlgarian and English US


Actually, I understand that I have general problems with some shortcuts. I edit my question.

Comment: If you use GNOME, you need to use GNOME Tweaks to set `<Alt+Shift>`. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/967493/66509).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The following steps fixed the issue for me:

- Go to Settings -> Region & Language
- Temporarily remove all other keyboard layouts, just leave Bulgarian.
- Try writing something - now you should see Bulgarian characters
- Finally, re-add the other keyboard layouts (English US in my case) and reorder them to suit
  your liking.

Comment: Hi, rapture,
Thanks for your attention. Unfortunately, this does not work for me :(

Actually, I understand that I have general problems with some shortcuts. I edit my question.