# Skype loses focus when changing keyboard layout with ALT+SHIFT

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, skype

This happens only in Skype on Ubuntu 18.04. I have used Skype on other platforms (Ubuntu and others) and this does not happen.
I use ALT+SHIFT to switch keyboard layout to another language. When I use Skype on Ubuntu 18.04 and press ALT+SHIFT the language is changed but also the focus is moved to the application menu (as if I had pressed ALT only).

Any help is welcome!

Comment: It seems to have already been fixed (I wrote to them several times via "Help -> Report a Problem..."). Ubuntu 20.04.4, Skype 8.83.0.408.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess the way you have set-up your ALT+SHIFT shortcut is via `gnome-tweak-tool`?

If that's the case - I have the same issue with `slack`, after some digging found out that there is another way to change the keyboard layout w/o using `gnome-tweak-tool` which wont cause this side effect of losing the focus.

The solution is to use `gsettings` as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/986629/567424)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Shift>Alt_L']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward "['<Alt>Shift_L']"
```

UPDATE: As mentioned in the comments, make sure to also uncheck the `ALT+SHIFT` shortcut from `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Todor. However I am afraid the result is the same for me at skype no matter if I use gnome-tweaks or gsettings.

Comment: @user9839468 make sure to also uncheck the "alt+shift" from "Switching to another layout" in the "keyboard and mouse" from the `gnome-tweak-tool`. I just had to fix it on one more machine and only applying the `gsettings` commands was not enough when I had "alt+shift" in `gnome-tweak-tool`. I also tested in on skype and it seems to work for me.

Comment: Yes, That worked! Thank you so much @Todor!

Comment: Hey, in my case it worked for the current session, but after I restarted the computer, the language indicator would change, but I could only type with the default keyboard

Answer (score 1):

That was an odd issue. It looks like pressing only <kbd>Alt</kbd> is a Skype specific shortcut. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, OTOH, is an XKB shortcut. One way to avoid that Skype is affected is to make sure you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> first and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> while still holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

Or, of course, using the default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is another way to avoid the conflict.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Both alternatives you propose involve changing the way of switching keyboard which is something I would like to avoid as I use it for longer than the last 20 years. As for all applications `Alt` is a shortcut to move to the menu, it is really odd as you say that this is the first time `Alt`+`Shift` has the side-effect of changing focus.