# How to show language chooser with Alt+Shift in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, keyboard, customization, input-language

In my Ubuntu 18.04, I set switching languages by <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, as shown in

**Settings**->**Devices**->**Keyboard**->**"Switch to next input source"**

and in the picture below, but it doesn't allow me to change keyboard layout with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as I used to do.

[image]

I can do it using Gnome Tweaks as shown below:

[image]

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, the language is switching but the language chooser doesn't appear, unlike <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> as per picture below:

[image]

How can I have language chooser shown by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, please?

Comment: AFAIK you can't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 17.10 and later: can't change the input switching shortcut to alt+shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to achieve what you want

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L']"
```

Comment: does this make the language chooser appear, or just set the keybinding?

Comment: The language chooser appears