# Alt-Shift combination hangs with cursor up in the menu

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I change keyboard layouts with Alt-Shift after some [tweaking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift/986629#986629) , but under various circumstances, it seems that only the Alt registers, making the cursor open some menu item. I have a vague memory of binding time/delay settings, but I can't find where to set it. presumably, I sometimes press too slow or too fast for Alt-Shift to work. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try the accepted answer, the setting under "Additional Layout Options"?

Comment: It was already set to Alt+Shift as in the accepted answer, but when I use it, it sometimes behaves as if I only press Alt

Comment: Please check what happens if you hold alt for a long moment after releasing shift.
As it now seems to me, the alt 'stays registered' for longer, or somethings like that

Comment: okay, I can recreate the problem when releasing the alt before the shift. I must hold alt, add shit, release shift and only then release alt, to get language change without getting stuck up there in the menus