# Switching languages shortcut - how to set a shortcut to Shift + Alt?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 21.10, 22.04

I saw in other posts that since Ubuntu switched to GNOME it's not possible to set language switching shortcut to two keys, such as Shift+Alt. I noticed it expects minimum 3 keys.

I saw the solution was to use GNOME-Tweaks but I don't want to use third party packages, is there any other option right now? Using Ubuntu 21.10 (And soon 22.04)

Or, GNOME-Tweaks is not a third party software?

Comment: Ubuntu returned to using GNOME by default back in 2017-October release, so it's not really recent. [GNOME Tweaks is a GNOME application](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks) so it's not a 3rd party application.

Comment: Make life easy and install Gnome Tweaks to do that. You can always remove it again.

Comment: thank you guys. installed (From Ubuntu Software, not `apt`, but I think it's the same)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 17.10 and later: can't change the input switching shortcut to alt+shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift)

Answer (score 1):

- Run `gnome-tweaks`
- Go to **Keyboard & Mouse** → **Additional Layout Options**
- Expand **Switching to another layout**
- Select **Alt+Shift**
- if you need right alt to switch language then go to **key to choose the 3rd level** and select **Right Alt never chooses 3rd level**