# Uubuntu 22.04 replace WIN + SPACE keyboard shortcut to Lshift + Alt to change keyboard layout/language

Tags: 22.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I want to change keyboard layout using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>.
What packages I need to do that. I know there is <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> option.

But I need shift+alt, ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching languages shortcut - how to set a shortcut to Shift + Alt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401636/switching-languages-shortcut-how-to-set-a-shortcut-to-shift-alt)

Comment: Note that doing this will break the indicator in the top bar: that will no longer be updated.

Comment: @vanadium: Yes, if Wayland it will ATM. It's [bug #1956916](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1956916).