# How to make Super+Shift or Shift+Space to change input language in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, language-support

I was able to make <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to change input language but then Gnome's default settings app made <kbd>Space</kbd> to change input language as well. It is not what I wanted.

I wasn't able to find <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd> in Gnome Tweak Tools.

Is there some place where I can manually enter key names for switching input language?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 17.10 and later: can't change the input switching shortcut to alt+shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift)

Answer (score 1):

In dconf editor go to this path and undo the setting that sets `<Space>` as a shortcut to switch the input source backward.

It is impossible to set `Shift + Super` to switch input language.

[image]