# Ubuntu 22.04 - keyboard indicator on toolbar doesn't change after pressing hotkey

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 22.04, gnome-tweaks

I'm using gnome-tweaks-tool to set an alternative hotkey for changing keyboard layout (`Ctrl+Shift`). It works - layout changes, but keyboard indicator on top toolbar doesn't change after pressing hotkey. If I use standart combination `Super+Space` layout and indicator on toolbar work good.

Can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 8):

After discussing the issue on the Ubuntu Launchpad it seems that it related to the Wayland session. Under Xorg, everything works fine.

To switch from Wayland to Xorg (from https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop):

```
sudo vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment the line:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

Restart GDM3 display manager:

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

Answer (score 4):

run this in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward "['<Control>Shift_L']"
```

got this answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift/967493#967493) - below the marked as right answer.

Comment: I think that this solution doesn't resolve the issue itself: the keyboard indicator doesn't change, when you change the keyboard layout. I'm looking for the way to deal with this issue too: it was broken after upgrade from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 LTS.

Comment: I was looking for a solution because I had this issue too (on fresh 22.04 installation). I Tried some things but that's the answer that solved the problem in my case. maybe it will help others too. @Zzaponka

Comment: I mean that in my opinion the solution you are referring to is about the way to assign different keys combination to switch between input layouts, but the current one is about issue with keyboard layout indicator itself that doesn't reflect the current layout.

Comment: Yes, I know, my issue was the same. I changed the key binding using Gnome-Tweaks and it indeed changed, but the indicator stayed the same. This line made it change the indicator too.

Comment: This actually solved my problem. Indicator started working.

Comment: I had the same problem and was reluctant to switch to X11, this solution fixed it. I think this should be the accepted answer