# Switching language by Alt + Shift after update from Ubuntu 22.04 beta to release is not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

Switching language settings made by Tweaks tool (`gnome-tweak-tool`) like described in accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift).

After performing update to release version by

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

language switching by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> stopped working. How to fix it?

Related question: [How to have Alt+Shift shortcut for language switching and be able to use other shortcuts that contain Alt+Shift combination keys?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1434452/1548713)

Comment: This is another of the myriad bugs in Wayland. Select normal non-Wayland (i.e. Xorg) Ubuntu session during login.

Comment: @FedKad I also noticed after moving from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 that temperature of working processor got a bit higher. Probably the reason also because of `Wayland`.

Comment: The rise in temperature, CPU, and memory consumption is probably due to _tracker_. You can Google "ubuntu disable tracker 22.04" to remove it.

Comment: As @FedKad mentioned, this is most likely a bug. Probably [bug #1956916](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1956916). Please feel free to add observations to that bug report, if you think they may be helpful to the investigation.

Comment: I confirm that as @FedKas said there are no problems with switching language under `Ubuntu Xorg`.

Answer (score 47):

Execute the following line by line in terminal on Ubuntu 22 LTS:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Shift>Alt_L']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward "['<Alt>Shift_L']"
```

Open *Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts (View and Customise Shortcuts) > Typing* to confirm changes.

[image]

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1956916/comments/38

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Based on it I'm at last was able to get to work other shortcuts containing `Alt` + `Shift`. Here is related question and answer - https://askubuntu.com/a/1434468/1548713

Comment: Looks like there is no way to set this combination using UI. Thanks)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 14):

Like in [recommended setup](https://askubuntu.com/a/967493/1548713):

- Launch `Tweaks` tool
- Go to `Keyboard & Mouse section`.
- Click on the `Additional Layout Options`. A new window should pop up.
- Look for `Switching to another layout` and expand it.

Here uncheck all checked options. Check `Alt+Shift` option again. Leave only one this option. Or only `Ctrl+Shift` if you prefer to use it.

After this `Alt + Shift` started working for me but in top right corner of the screen there was no information about corresponding switch - seems to bug introduced in Ubuntu 22.04. In Ubuntu 20.04 this function worked fine.

`Win + Space` also works normally (with updating of corresponding information about current language in top right corner) even if unchecked in `Tweeks`.

Comment: fw up on the bug in Ubuntu 22.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1956916
As a temporary workaround, use a Super(Win)+Space shortcut in layouts (multiple can be used, but Alt + Shift won't be reflected as input indicator change)

Comment: You solved my long-time problem with ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 9):

1. Use gnome-tweaks to set shortcut
2. For Ubuntu 22.04: Open /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and uncomment "WaylandEnable=false" than save it and reboot. This step makes layout indication work. (and xdotool too...)

Answer (score 2):

Look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1956916/comments/38

In short:
Use `dconf editor`, navigate to `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings.switch-input-source` and set it to `'<Alt>Shift_L'`

Answer (score 2):

Here it is for Alt-Shift / Shift-Alt **on both keyboard sides**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L', '<Shift>Alt_L', '<Alt>Shift_R', '<Shift>Alt_R']"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).