# How to have Alt+Shift shortcut for language switching and be able to use other shortcuts that contain Alt+Shift combination keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

I configured language switching by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> combination by means of Ubuntu `Tweeks`.
But after that other shortcuts that include <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys stopped working. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in `PyCharm` IDE.

As work around I configured <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> for switching language. For it to work standard shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> and all other language switching shortcuts must be disabled. After this I can use <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> in other shortcuts. So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> is working

`On Windows 7` there was no similar problem.
Is this Ubuntu bug? This behavior is actual for Ubuntu `22.04` and `20.04`.

Related question: [Switching language by Alt + Shift after update from Ubuntu 22.04 beta to release is not working](https://askubuntu.com/q/1407560/1548713)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recipe for Ubuntu `20.04`:

Remove all shortcuts for language switching in `Tweeks` (`Additional Layout Options` -> `Switching to another layout`).

Just in case backup the parameters:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source
# ['<Super>space', 'XF86Keyboard']
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward
# ['<Shift><Super>space', '<Shift>XF86Keyboard']
```

Set the parameters:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward "['<Alt>Shift_L', '<Shift>XF86Keyboard']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L', 'XF86Keyboard']"
```

Check `Settings` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts`, filter by `source` keyword.

`Switching to next input source` should become `Alt+Shift L`.

`Switching to previous input source` should become `Alt+Shift L`.

Like on the picture below:
[image: language switching config in settings]

Switching language now should work by `Alt + Left Shift`. Holding `Alt` and pressing `Left Shift` should show standard language menu in the center of screen.

`Ctrl + Alt + Shift + T` shortcut should work by means of either left or right keys.

To be able to use, for example, `Alt + Shift + C` shortcut in IDE `Shift` should be pressed and hold first, then `Alt` + `C`.
Otherwise `Alt` first + `Shift` will switch the language.