# /etc/default/keyboard ignored?

Tags: keyboard-layout, 22.04, xkb

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 (jammy) LTS.  My ultimate goal is to have the following keyboard layout configuration:

- U.S. international (with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> dead keys) and Russian keyboard layouts;
- switching between them using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (toggle) and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> (temporarily);
- Having left <kbd>Logo</kbd> key as the compose key.

The behaviour I'm getting is that I seem to have **two** U.S. layouts, and one of them ignores <kbd>AltGr</kbd> in console.

---

My `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="compose:lwin,grp:caps_switch,grp:lalt_lshift_toggle,nbsp:level3n,terminate:ctrl_alt
_bksp"
XKBVARIANT="altgr-intl,"
```

The output of `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10`:

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)"     };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};
```

The output of `gsettings list-recursively  'org.gnome.desktop.input-sources'`:

```
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current uint32 0
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources [('xkb', 'us+altgr-intl'), ('xkb', 'ru')]
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources per-window false
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources false
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources [('xkb', 'us+altgr-intl'), ('xkb', 'ru')]
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options ['terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp', 'nbsp:level3n', 'grp:lalt_lshift_toggle', 'grp:caps_switch', 'lv3:ralt_switch', 'compose:lwin']
```

I've tried both `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, rebooting and all.  No effect.

Is there anything I'm forgetting?

Comment: Weird. All I can think of is the order of the keys. I have this order: XKBMODEL, XKBLAYOUT, XKBVARIANT, XKBOPTIONS, BACKSPACE

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, changing that, unfortunately, didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, which thing fixed it, but I did the following:

1. Removed `~/.xinputrc`.
2. Used `im-config` to set input method selection to `default`.
3. Did what this comment recommends: [Ubuntu 17.10 and later: can't change the input switching shortcut to alt+shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift/986629#comment1667383_986629).

This seems to have fixed the switching issue, although I cannot access my English layout's third level by pressing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> simultaneously.  But I guess, that will be another question, heh.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after installing debian-live-12.5.0-amd64-standard (Bookworm).
The solution that I found was to run the following commands under root :

```
cd /etc/console-setup/
mv ./cached_UTF_8_del.kmap.gz ./cached_UTF_8_del.kmap.gz.backup
setupcon
```

This working answer was explained [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=125498):

> Re: Editing /etc/default/keyboard has no effect
>
> Tue Nov 10, 2015 12:38 pm Yes, sure...
>
> The script setupcon is responsible for setting up font and keyboard
> layout for console. For keyboard layout, it reads the file
> /etc/default/keyboard and generates an output file,
> /etc/console-setup/cached_UTF_8_del.kmap.gz in my case, other names
> are possible.
>
> setupcon does not always generate this output file, it first checks if
> /etc/default/keyboard is NEWER than cached_UTF_8_del.kmap.gz
>
> My RetroPie image was released in summer 2015, the timestamp of
> cached_UTF_8_del.kmap.gz[ was 26.3.2015 for this release. Problem was,
> i tried to change the layout on a "virgin" Retropie, no internet
> connection yet. The HW-clock was set to some date in 2014 as default
> value.
>
> Thus, you can change /etc/default/keyboard as often as you want, it
> will always be recogniozed as older than cached_UTF_8_del.kmap.gz due
> to the wrong HW-clock, thus, cached_UTF_8_del.kmap.gz is never be
> refreshed.
>
> Quick solution: delete your cached_UTF_8_del.kmap.gz, forcing setupcon
> to generate it again. Or, set your date using
>
> Code: Select all
>
> date -s
>
> I never used a vanilla Raspbian image, however, I'm wondering why I
> didn't find something related to this issue after hours of googling.
> Can't believe I'm the first one encountering this issue...

thanks lugge !