# Ubuntu not showing language options or input swapping after adding a language

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, input-language

I added Norwegian for my wife on Ubuntu Jellyfish under settings however while I'm able to add Norwegian the language icon does not appear in the top right corner like it usually does. It has previously worked on this laptop. Before giving it to her I had a Mandarin input and it worked as the tutorial described. I also tried following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/967493/638863) to make it so winkey+space changes the input and the input change does not show on screen and does not change the input despite Norwegian showing under input sources.

Am I doing something silly? It seems like a bug, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: 1) The procedure is three steps. Go to settings, keyboards, add language. I just removed the tutorial. 2) There's only one command and it's to install a package. It makes setting up keyboard shortcuts more convienient and I only did it to show that didn't work in addition to the icon not appearing. Something anyone who uses multiple languages alreadyy knows. Moreover, it's perfectly normal to crosslink to other SE sites. I'm not sure how you meant your comment to come across but it seems openly hostile and it also seems like you may not be familiar with this subject.

Comment: You may have hit [bug #1956916](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1956916). But to sort it out, can you please edit your question and let us know the output of these two terminal commands: 1. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`