# Keyboard switching shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys

How can I make this setting permanent:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options []
```

I type it every time when I login because I can't use left ctrl + shift it is switching keyboards for me I don't want to use it for switching keyboards.

Ubuntu 22.04, GNOME 42.9, Mutter
,

Comment: Have you tried removing the shortcut from the GUI?

Comment: How? It is set somewhere in console it asked to set shortcut when I upgraded to 22.04

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the Ubuntu flavor you are using, so we know if it is Gnome or XFCE or whatever. But the control center/setting app of the GUI should have a place for you to change this.

Comment: I thought that gsettings are only available on gnome?

Comment: No, it used to work with unity if I remember correctly and certainly works with cinnamon and most likely budgie, and probably others I don't know.  So, if you're using Gnome, isn't there a control center thing where you can go to something like "keyboard => language" or similar (sorry, I haven't used gnome since the time of gnome2). Maybe [this](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/967364/85695)?

Comment: yeah, but... The command I put there is the one I want to use... Win + Space This was I asked during upgrade I think it's default shortcut... And gets reverted after each reboot... I can't find where is it being set

Comment: That's why I am suggesting that instead of running that which doesn't seem to persist across reboots, you instead try to clear the shortcut using the standard GUI tool. I mean, sure you can run that command every time you log in by adding something like `sleep 10 && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options []` as the last line f your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, or you can use Gnome's autorun functionality and have it run on login, but these are ugly hacks while just unsetting the shortcut from the settings might be a final solution.

Comment: yeah, thanks for the idea... That will definetley work, better than using systemd

Comment: @AleksandarPavić you can lock the gsettings key. Have you tried that?

Comment: How to lock gsettings key?