# UBUNTU 23.10, how set Alt-Shift conbination shortcut to switch languages?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 23.10

I just switched from ZORIN to UBUNTU 23.10 and decided to set the switching language shortcut. I use English (US) and Greek keyboard layouts.
I do the following steps:

1. Settings
2. Keyboard
3. View and customize shortcuts
4. Typing
5. Switch to next input source.

Then I see this screen and unfortunately I can only set a combination of three keys, not two (Alt-Shift)

[image]

Does anyone know how to set the Alt-Shift keys to change language?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 17.10 and later: can't change the input switching shortcut to alt+shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it from command-line (in the terminal) using [`dconf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/mantic/en/man1/dconf.1.html) for the `switch-input-source` key like so:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L']"
```

... and for the `switch-input-source-backward` key like so:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-input-source-backward "['<Shift>Alt_L']"
```

**Notice** that you can reset both keys to their default values anytime with:

```
dconf reset /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-input-source
```

... and:

```
dconf reset /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-input-source-backward
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can't do it from there. But, you can do it with `gnome-tweaks`. Please, install it if it is not already installed.

Run `gnome-tweaks`, go to **Keyboard & Mouse** → **Additional Layout Options** → **Switching to another layout** and select **Alt+Shift**.

Comment: Thank you very much! The previous answer worked but since I like experiments, I'll try this one too!