# Delay when switch keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am new here on Ubuntu.

I am using 2 language keyboard layout Persian and when I press switch keyboard layout key, It shows language switch and delay about 1-2 sec before I can start to type again.

Is any possible way to remove this delay?

[image]

Comment: install gnome-tweaks with the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` then from there you can set keyboard shortcut which will not show this popup n straightaway changes the language..

Comment: go through this answer and pics in it https://askubuntu.com/a/1031456/739431

Answer (score 0):

I found the [answer on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/84453o/delayfreezecpu_spike_when_using_the_functionmedia/). As [murilomentor](https://www.reddit.com/user/murilomentor/) said in [his reply](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/84453o/comment/e5ekzdk/) to [Pacheko17](https://www.reddit.com/user/Pacheko17/):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Open the keyboard layout file for your language, example:-

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br
   ```
2. Comment the following line:

   ```
   modifier_map Mod3 { Scroll_Lock };
   ```
3. Logout and log in again.

Their original post:

> 1. Opened the keyboard layout file for my language, in my case:
>
>    ```
>    sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br
>    ```
> 2. Commented the line:
>
>    ```
>    modifier_map Mod3 { Scroll_Lock };
>    ```
> 3. Logged out and logged in again.

It worked for me!